# python can't parse json string

Tags: python, json

I tried to parse json data but it didn't work, json parser return a strong not a dictionary!!
Here the code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import json
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.imdb.com//name/nm0425005/mediaviewer/rm244453632?ref_=nmmi_mi_all_sf_49").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
script = soup.find('script', {'id': 'imageJson'})
json_data = ''.join(map(str, script.contents))
json_data = json.dumps(json_data.strip(' \t\n\r'))
data = json.loads(json_data)
print data['mediaViewerModel']
```

Comment: yes I printed the json data before pass it to json module, yet it looks alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json_data = ''.join(map(str, script.contents))
>>> json_data = json.dumps(json_data.strip(' \t\n\r'))
data = json.loads(json_data)
```

The marked line is the problem. `json_data` is currently a string encoding a dictionary, and when you call `json.dumps`, it will then be a string encoding a string encoding a dictionary, and your last line just undoes one instance. What is it that you're actually trying to do with the marked line?

Comment: I tried only loads to load the function but it didn't works, I got this error: ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 2 column 515 (char 515)
I add dumps I thought it will fix the syntax of json

Comment: That's telling you that what you're trying to parse isn't valid JSON. Since you're scraping it from a site, you're probably getting something back without proper escaping or something vs. what you'd get from an API.